# How to add external data to database using rake db:seed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I have the following in my seeds.rb file.  When I run rake db:seed, I get an error saying:

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - MSFT_1_100.json
```

This displays even though I have the file 'MSFT_1_100.json' in the same folder as the seeds.rb file (/project/db).  Any advice on how to fix this?

```
require 'json'
file_name = 'MSFT_1_100.json'

data = File.open(file_name, "r").read
my_object = JSON.load(data)
my_object.each do |item|
    new_review = Review.create(:company => 'Microsoft', :pro => item['pro'], :con => item['con'], :advice => item['advice'], :role => item['role'])
end
```

Comment: i have edited my post please check it once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to do this instead of just giving the file_name directly

```
file_name = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'MSFT_1_100.json'))
```

Comment: It worked!  Why does the rest of this need to be added?  Can you point me to where I can read up more on this?

Comment: read about absolute path and relative path.when you give the file name directly it searches the Rails root directory. so you need to point exactly where the file is.... You can use any of the techniques relative or absolute paths